# Android Value Animator increase/decrease consecutively without skipping any number

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using `ValueAnimator` in following manner

```
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    valueAnimator.setObjectValues(1000, 20000);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(5000);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()      {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int animatedValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            System.out.println("Values "+animatedValue);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
```

While doing this, the `valueAnimator` object, skips numbers i.e. it is not counting consecutively like `1000,1001,1002..`and so on. It does similar to this `1000,1000,1000,1002,1004,1008...` and so on. I am using `valueAnimator` for currency counting and I need to find out certain specific amount like `2000,3000,4000`.So, is there any way we can use `valueAnimator` to increase/decrease number by count of 1 i.e. without skipping any number in between .

Comment: no, `Animator`s are not designed for that

Comment: @pskink... Thank you I will use `Handlers` then.